# Linux SSH Config Alias Permission Denied (publickey)

Tags: linux, mac, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS linux instance running that I'm trying to SSH into. When I type in the manual command (using mac, terminal):

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/PEM.pem root@IPADDRESS
```

it works fine, but when I try to give that an alias in the config file in my SSH colder, such as

```
Host hostname
User root
IdentityFile "file"
HostName IPADDRESS
```

I get the error:

`Permission denied (publickey)`.

I have other AWS aliases in my config file with the exact same setup that work fine, any ideas? Thanks.

**Update** I figured out what was going on here, I had a trailing whitespace at the end of my .pem location. Man is that stuff finicky.

Comment: have you looked at hosts.allow and hosts.deny? I'd also check out /var/log/secure and /var/log/messages on the AWS linux instance and see what they have to say.

Comment: Try `ssh -v`, it will dump a _lot_ of information, maybe some will be useful. (`-vv` for even more info. :)

Comment: @Caleb, good catch. Add it as an answer and accept it, so others might be spared going nuts. :)

Comment: Also, make sure there is a 600 permission on whole .ssh and content of it

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what was going on here, I had a trailing whitespace at the end of my .pem location. Man is that stuff finicky.